# Are properties in C# and descriptors and properties in Python some design pattern?

Tags: c#, python, design-patterns

Are properties in C# and descriptors and properties in Python some design pattern? I didn't see they belong to any in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern.
Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't consider a language feature to be a design pattern. After all, how would you implement it in a language that didn't have it? If you can't, it's not a pattern.

Comment: If I am correct, Java doesn't have properties. So would an implementation of a property in Java be a design pattern?

Comment: Java does not have properties as language feature, but getter and setter methods are identical (although more tedious to write and read), so I'd say: Java has the same properties you can find in C#, but you have to implement them manually.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it a design pattern. C# properties are [mutator methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method):

> In computer science, a mutator method is a method used to control changes to a variable. They are also widely known as setter methods. Often a setter is accompanied by a getter (also known as an accessor), which returns the value of the private member variable.

I don't know any Python, but since you lump them together in your question, I assume the concept is the same.